# Client validation for collection of items Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

In short - on my View, data-validation attributes are added only for inputs of the firs object from the colletion. I want to be able to validate inputs of any object of the collection on my View. I am using Asp.net MVC4, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

More detailed:
I have an Admin page in my project, where I want to displya all product categories. Any of this categories can be edited. In the end of edition process, user can click button to save all changes.

My ViewModel:

```
public class CategoriesManagementViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = Validation.FieldRequiredMsg)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Validation.FieldRequiredMsg)]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = Validation.MaxLength50Msg)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Validation.FieldRequiredMsg)]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = Validation.PositiveNumberMsg)]
    public int AmountForDiscount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = Validation.FieldRequiredMsg)]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = Validation.PercentMsg )]
    public int DiscountPercent { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Here is controller:

```
public JsonResult GetProductCategories(int currentPage)
    {
        using (var service = new DalServiceSoapClient())
        {
            var data = service.GetProductCategories(currentPage, Constants.ItemsOnPage,false)
                .Select(x=> new CategoriesManagementViewModel(x));
            var html = RenderRazorViewToString("_ManageCategoriesPartial", data);
            return Json(new { status = "success", html = html });
        }

    }
```

In controller I am getting data from db, converting it to collection of my ViewModels and passing to Partial View. Partial view is rendered to html string, sent as json and a part of my view is updated.

Here is partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GreenLightShop.Models.CategoriesManagementViewModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
    var i = 0;
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var blockedClass = "";    
    var blockBtnCaption = "Block";

if (!item.IsActive)
{
    blockedClass = "blocked";
    blockBtnCaption = "UnBlock";
}

<div class='box @blockedClass' itemid="@item.Id" ischanged="false" isactive     ="@item.IsActive">

    <div class="show">
        <span>@item.Name</span>
        |&nbsp;<a href="#" class="edit-category-btn">Edit Category</a>
        |&nbsp;<a href="#" class="edit-products-btn">Edit Product</a>
        |&nbsp;<a href="#" class="block-btn"> @blockBtnCaption </a> |&nbsp;
    </div>
    <form class="edit hidden">

        <div class="form-field">
            <label> Name:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Name)
         @*   @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ElementAt(i).Name)*@
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).Name)    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label> Amount For Discount:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).AmountForDiscount)
           @* @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).AmountForDiscount)*@
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).AmountForDiscount)    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-field">
            <label> Discount:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).DiscountPercent)
           @* @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).DiscountPercent)*@
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ElementAt(i).DiscountPercent)    
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="button" class="accept-changes-btn" value="Apply"/>
        <input type="button" class="cancel-changes-btn" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
</div>

    i++;
}
```

For the first element of 
`IEnumerable<GreenLightShop.Models.CategoriesManagementViewModel>`, validation attributes are added to each input on the form.

```
<input id="Name" type="text" value="CategoryName" name="Name" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length="Not longer than 50 characters." data-val="true">.
```

Validation works fine.

For inputs of all other categories validation attributes are not added.

```
<input id="Name" type="text" value="AnotherCategory" name="Name">
```

when user click

```
<input type="button" class="accept-changes-btn" value="Apply"/>`,
```

I am parsing input fields of modified category with `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this));`

All categories are displayed normally and when I submit changes Model.IsValid works fine and data binding also works.

How can I make validation for each category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I've found:
The problem was that for each form I was using `<Form>` tag. When I've changed it to `@using(Html.BeginForm())` problem was fixed. Now every input in every form on my view has validation atributes.

If anybody know the explanation, why this is happening, I would love to hear it.